# Cannot update my github personal access token to watson studio

Tags: git, github, watson-studio, personal-access-token

I try to update my personal acces token, beacuse the old one is expired, but watson studio won't let me, forcing me to use the old token

I generate a new token but the option of changing its not possible

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update a token in Watson Studio (Cloud Pak for Data), but you can create a new one, then delete the old.

Doc Link: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.5.x?topic=project-accessing-git-repository